# Jasper Reports - how to pass parameter to ResourceRenderer.getInstance()?

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I have the following to display an image on my report:

```
<parameter name="fundo" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false"/>

<image>
    <reportElement x="56" y="36" width="102" height="62" uuid="6473c069-834e-40ff-a3ac-52cb2a7b83c8"/>
    <imageExpression><![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.ResourceRenderer.getInstance("$P{fundo}", false)]]></imageExpression>
</image>
```

What should I pass to "fundo" parameter from Java?

```
    Map<String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<>(2);
    parameters.put("fundo", ??);
```

The image is an .svg resource.

Tried this:

```
public static String getFundo() {
    URL resource = ImageUtil.class.getClassLoader().getResource("fundo.svg");

    if (resource == null) {
        return null;
    }

    return resource.toExternalForm();
}
```

Got this exception:

```
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Byte data not found at: ((java.lang.String)parameter_fundo.getValue()).
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the quotes around `$P{fundo}`

As in

```
<imageExpression><![CDATA[net.sf.jasperreports.renderers.ResourceRenderer.getInstance($P{fundo}, false)]]></imageExpression>
```

Answer (score -2):

You should read it as byte, something like

```
$P{fundo}.getBytes("UTF-8")
```

Regard, Mohamad

Comment: But the method does not take bytes, It takes a string named resourceLocation.